# How to identify mysqli_stmt_fetch return 0

Tags: php, if-statement, pdo

How can I dispaly "no item " when database have no values.here is my code and where should I need to put `else{ echo 'No item';}`

```
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT id,name,price,image FROM product Limit ?,8")) {

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $page_1);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,$ids,$title,$prc,$image);

        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {

        $id = $ids;
        $pst_title = $title;
        $price = $prc;
        $pst_image = $image;
        $price = number_format($price, 2); 

        echo '    <article>';
        echo "    <img src='admin/gem/$pst_image' alt='images'></td>";
        echo "    <h3>$pst_title</h3>";
        echo "    <h4>$.$price</h4>";
        echo "    <a href='gem.php?id={$id}' class='btn-add'>View more</a>";
        echo '    </article>';                                      
        }

}
```

Comment: Could set a counter in your while statement or is there a `num_results` style element in PDO? `if($stmt->fetchColumn() > 0)` or the like?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the number of rows returned by the query, by accessing the `num_rows` property. However, for it to hold the correct value, you need to store the results first, by using `mysqli_stmt_store_result()`. See the revised code below, with the added comments.

```
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT id,name,price,image FROM product Limit ?,8")) {

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $page_1);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,$ids,$title,$prc,$image);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt); // Store the result into memory
    if (mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt)) { // Check the number of rows returned
        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {

             $id = $ids;
             $pst_title = $title;
             $price = $prc;
             $pst_image = $image;
             $price = number_format($price, 2); 

             echo '    <article>';
             echo "    <img src='admin/gem/$pst_image' alt='images'></td>";
             echo "    <h3>$pst_title</h3>";
             echo "    <h4>$.$price</h4>";
             echo "    <a href='gem.php?id={$id}' class='btn-add'>View more</a>";
             echo '    </article>';                                      
        }
    } else {
        echo 'No item';
    }
}
```

- [PHP.net on `mysqli_stmt::$num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php)
- [PHP.net on `mysqli_stmt::store_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php)

Answer (score 1):

This would be a much nicer way of doing things: http://php.net/manual/ro/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

```
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT id,name,price,image FROM product Limit ?,8")) {

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $page_1);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);//thanks to Qirel
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,$ids,$title,$prc,$image);
    if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt)>0){
        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {

        $id = $ids;
        $pst_title = $title;
        $price = $prc;
        $pst_image = $image;
        $price = number_format($price, 2); 

        echo '    <article>';
        echo "    <img src='admin/gem/$pst_image' alt='images'></td>";
        echo "    <h3>$pst_title</h3>";
        echo "    <h4>$.$price</h4>";
        echo "    <a href='gem.php?id={$id}' class='btn-add'>View more</a>";
        echo '    </article>';                                      
        }
    }else{
            echo 'No item';
    }
}
```

Comment: From the PHP manual: "*The use of `mysqli_stmt_num_rows()` depends on whether or not you used `mysqli_stmt_store_result()` to buffer the entire result set in the statement handle. If you use `mysqli_stmt_store_result()`, `mysqli_stmt_num_rows()` may be called immediately.*"